# Typing switch statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a react component. That component recieves list, type.
List is an array of objects. Type is just an optional enum string.
Inside this component I have a function that's simply a switch case.
I want to enforce a specific type in each CASE statement.

Simple example below.
ERROR MESSAGE: : Property 'pk' does not exist on type 'combinedInterfaces'.
Property 'pk' does not exist on type 'basicInterface'.

Array1:

```
[
  {some: {id: 1}, name: 'John'},
  {some: {id: 2}, name: 'Jan'},
]
```

Array2:

```
[
  {pk: 1, some: { id: 12}, name: 'John'},
  {pk: 2, some: { id: 13}, name: 'Jan'},
]
```

Rendering my components:

```
<MyComponent list={array1} />
<MyComponent list={array2} type={typesList.myType} />
```

Content of MyComponent

```
export enum typesList {
  myType = 'myType'
}

interface basicInterface {
  some: {
    id: number;
  },
  name: string;
} 

interface myTypeInterface extends basicInterface{
  pk: number;
}

type listType = Array<combinedInterfaces>

type combinedInterfaces = myTypeInterface | basicInterface;


type MyComponentProps = {
  list: listType,
  type: typesList
}

const MyComponent = ({list, type}: MyComponentProps) => {
  const handleType = (item: combinedInterfaces) => {
    switch (type) {
      case typesList.myType: {
        return {
          id: item.pk (ERROR HERE)
        }
      }
      default: {
        return {
          id: item.some.id
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const handledList = useMemo(() => list.map(item => handleType(item),[list])

  return (
    <>
      {handledList.map(item =>
        <div>
         {item.id}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a typecast for `item`, like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({list, type}: MyComponentProps) => {
  const handleType = (item: combinedInterfaces) => {
    switch (type) {
      case typesList.myType: {
        return {
          id: (item as myTypeInterface).pk
        }
      }
      default: {
        return {
          id: (item as basicInterface).some.id
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this sufficient? "as" is enforcing types and I could provide anything.

Comment: As I understood, you cannot provide whatever object, but only objects of myTypeInterface or basicInterface.

Comment: @adammo Was this answer good enough? If so please mark as correct (the community appreciates) or feel free to ask for more help.